Representation of algebras with involution
Let $K$ be a field with involution $-:K \to K$. Let $A$ be a unital $K$-algebra with involution $*:A \to A$ such that $(a\cdot1_A)^*=\bar{a}\cdot1_A$ for $a \in K$. Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space with nondegenerate form $\beta: V \times V \to K$ such that $\beta(au,bv)=a\bar{b}\beta(u,v)$ for all $a,b \in K$. We define adjoint involution with respect to $\beta$ in $\text{End}_K(V)$.
Has anyone seen representation $\rho: A \to \text{End}_K(V)$ preserving involution in a context other than $C^*$-algebra or different than when $K =\mathbb{C}$?
When $K=\mathbb{C}$, $-$ is complex conjugate, $\beta$ is a sesqulinear form, and $\rho$ is called unitary representation. When $K=\mathbb{R}$, $-$ is identity map, $\beta$ is a bilenear form, and $\rho$ is called orthogonal representation. But what about other cases? Do we have such a thing as an involutive representation?
I want some references in this regard.

I think this is certainly done in the context of algebraic groups over number fields or local fields. Probably the "Book of Involutions" is kind of the bible for this theory: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/involutions.pdf

Thank you Torsten
